# Memory overflow with SSE-C++

Tags: c++, sse

I have a scenario

```
     int N3 =7000
    temp =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int )*N3);

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N3;i++)
    {
              temp[i]=i;
    }



    temp = temp +10;
    __m128i* array= reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(temp);
   int length = N3/4;

   for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;i++)
   {
      __m128i answer= _mm_loadu_si128(&array[i]);
   }
```

I think memory overflow is happening here. How we can avoid this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the block:

```
temp = temp +10;
__m128i* sse_array = reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(temp);
int length = N3/4;

for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
   __m128i result = _mm_loadu_si128(&sse_array[i]);
}
```

You are treating `temp+10` like it is `temp`. By the time the `for` loop ends, you are accessing more than the memory you allocated by `10*sizeof(int)` memory locations.

**PS**

Don't used a hard coded number, like `4`, when computing `length`. Use:

```
int length = N3*sizeof(int)/size(__m128i);
```